# MySQL - Converting ANSI to Unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, mojibake

Somehow, data in MySQL database has been converted from Unicode to ANSI and caused a lot of the symbols that are in the system to display incorrectly.

Symbols now display like:

- â€“
- â€¢
- â‚¸
- Î©
- etc.

I would like to convert it back to Unicode...
I have tried:

- Re-importing the database as UTF8 character set
- Using Notepad++ to "convert to UTF8..."
- Added default charset UTF8 to Apache config...
- A PHP script that takes all the DBs and tables, copies them, converts the data, then re-creates the original databases.

These methods did not work out... they seem to just leave my data the way it is, but any future attempts to use symbols works fine. 
I want to convert these existing misinterpretations back to their original forms!

---

Hex output of an example text from the DB.

```
SELECT hex(name) FROM table_name where id = 17;
```

which is equivalent to:  `SELECT hex('â˜¼STICKYâ˜¼');`

OUTPUT: `C3A2CB9CC2BC535449434B59C3A2CB9CC2BC`

Comment: Do you see the mangled characters using phpMyAdmin? It is possible that your data in mysql are correct and only you can't see them correctly.

Comment: The data is showing the "mangled characters" from within mysql as well as from the application (browser).

Using the application to place symbols into the database works fine NOW. Existing "mangled characters" stay mangled.

I have been using the database and application with symbols just fine until early this week.

Comment: Does using phpMyAdmin tend to cause this type of encoding error???
I am trying to understand why this has happened. I feel like it happened from some other admin doing export/import/backup/restore using phpMyAdmin... but its basically just a shot in the dark. I do not use phpMyAdmin to interact with my db

Comment: I had similar experience where everything was displayed properly on webpage but phpMyAdmin showed it as like in your example. It turned out to be a problem of default connection between PHP and MySQL, not related to phpMyAdmin at all.

Comment: I had similar experience when I exported data and then re-imported it.
Using the --default-character-set was the thing i forgot in the mysqldump command:mysqldump --host=<host> --user=<user> --single-transaction --default-character-set=utf8 <database> > <file>

Comment: @TomasM I somewhat suspected something similar to that so I have added UTF8 as the default character set to the apache configs. Should I do something similar for php.ini??? is there something similar?

Comment: What resolved my issue was manually adjusting all mysql queries in PHP, every time I connected to database I had to do the following command in PHP: mysqli_query($mysqli_link,"SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); Then everything worked just fine, importing the UTF-8 strings to database was OK and phpMyAdmin shows correct letters. I do not know if there is any pnp.ini config to set UTF8 as default connection encoding.

Comment: It looks like there can be added the following to php.ini: "default_charset utf-8" ... however I'm not sure if this has any meaning for mysql connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you showed looked somewhat like "double encoding" and discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll .  Please dump a little of the text in hex for confirmation.

To clarify, you are probably looking at utf8 (not unicode) versus latin1 (not ANSI).

@Tomas M - In PHP, `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` is the proper call, not SET NAMES utf8.

However, if the data is mangled in the table(s), that call will not help.

(Edit -- added after HEX by OP)

```
mysql> SELECT hex(convert(convert(unhex('C3A2CB9CC2BC') using utf8) using latin1));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(convert(convert(unhex('C3A2CB9CC2BC') using utf8) using latin1)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| E298BC                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT unhex('E298BC');
+-----------------+
| unhex('E298BC') |
+-----------------+
| ☼               |
+-----------------+
```

Is '☼' what you were expecting before 'STICKY'?  You had "double encoding"; it took 2 steps to decode it.

Comment: how do i get the hex for the text in the db??

Comment: is it really UTF8 vs latin1?? I thought I had tried conversions from unicode to ANSI and got similar results... what are the differences??
edited my question to include the hex output. thanks!

Comment: Unicode is a specification for characters; utf8 (and utf16 and utf32) are ways to express it in computer bytes.  ASCII (not ANSI) is a 7-bit encoding (128 codes) that works for English.  latin1 is an 8-bit encoding that covers most Western European languages.  My charcoll blog discusses this more.  Minor variants of latin1 go by a number of different names.